# Are GMRES and CG iterations the same for SPD matrix?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Just curious, I know computationally, due to storage, cg would be the best when A is SPD. However I am curious if just their iterations are the same? My intuition says no, but if someone could confirm this for me that would be great.

Comment: In my opinion the title is ok.  But for the record, CG refers to the conjugate gradient method and SPD means "symmetric positive definite". Here's a link with background info about the GMRES method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_minimal_residual_method

Comment: Related (https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/7031)

Comment: CG , GMRES, SPD are standard abbreviations in the field of scientific computing and are universally used in talks. I rarely see SPD used in journals, but CG and GMRES common in journals and books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not. Consider the solution of the linear system $Ax=b$, starting with the initial guess $x_0 = 0$. After $k$ iterations GMRES minimizes the 2-norm of the residual $r_k = b - Ax_k$ over the Krylov subspace $K_k(A,b)$. In contrast, CG minimizes the A-norm of the error $e_k = x - x_k$ over the same space. These results can be found in Saad's book "Iterative methods for sparse linear systems".

Comment: Starting from that conceptual description of CG, is it easy to derive the CG iteration?

Comment: @littleO: I have never seen it done. If you find a way, then I would be extremely happy to include it in my lectures and notes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. @littleO you can derive CG from minimize the quadratic form x^t A x -b^tx. If we assume that A is SPD, then we can easily show that the gradient is Ax-b, and the Hessian is A. This is key because necc. condition for optimization is gradient=0, so we recoverAx=b, futhermore, the fact that the hessian is positive definite, means the x that satisfies this cost function is also a global minimizer - this is due to second order sufficient conditions for an optimizer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_0$ be an initial guess to the solution of $Ax=b$ and $r_0=b-Ax_0$ be the corresponding residual vector. Krylov subspace methods construct approximations  $x_k\in x_0+c_k$, where $c_k\in K_k$ and $K_k:=\mathrm{span}(r_0,Ar_0,\ldots,A^{k-1}r_0)$. A particular method is determined by the way how $c_k$ is constructed.

The GMRES method chooses $c_k:=c_k^{\rm GMRES}$ such that the 2-norm of the residual is minimal:
$$
\|r_k^{\rm GMRES}\|_2=\|r_0-Ac_k^{\rm GMRES}\|_2=\min_{c\in K_k}\|r_0-Ac\|_2.
$$
Since $Ac\in AK_k$ this turns out to be equivalent to
$$
r_k^{\rm GMRES}\perp AK_k.
$$

Another method, called FOM [here](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/IterMethBook_2ndEd.pdf) (full orthogonalization method), generates $c_k:=c_k^{\rm FOM}$ such that 
$$
r_k^{\rm FOM} \perp K_k.
$$
Now, this turns out to be equivalent to minimizing the $A$-norm of the error, exactly as CG does, provided that $A$ is SPD. Note that with $e_k:=x-x_0=A^{-1}r_k$, we have
$$
\|e_k\|_A = \|r_k\|_{A^{-1}} = \|A^{-1/2}(r_0-Ac_k)\|_2.
$$
If we want this to be minimal, we need $A^{-1/2}r_k\perp A^{1/2}K_k$, which is equivalent to $r_k\perp K_k$.

Consequently, CG is *not* equivalent to GMRES, but is *mathematically* equivalent to FOM. I say "mathematically" because FOM is based on the full orthogonalization by the Arnoldi method, while CG uses short recurrences and thus the latter is very sensitive to rounding errors. So while the methods are equivalent on the paper, there can generate different iterates when implemented on a computer with finite precision.

One relation between GMRES and FOM is worth mentioning (see Prop. 6.13 in the referenced book) which reveals a sort of equivalence of the two methods on a certain condition:
$$
\|r_k^{\rm FOM}\|_2=\frac{\|r_k^{\rm GMRES}\|_2}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\|r_k^{\rm GMRES}\|_2}{\|r_{k-1}^{\rm GMRES}\|_2}\right)^2}}.
$$
Hence $\|r_k^{\rm FOM}\|_2\approx \|r_k^{\rm GMRES}\|_2$ provided that $\|r_k^{\rm FOM}\|_2\ll \|r_{k-1}^{\rm FOM}\|_2$. So, for example, if GMRES has fast convergence for a certain problem (e.g., with a good preconditioner), the residual norms of the generated iterates are very close for both methods (note that this does not necessarily mean that the iterates need to be close if $A$ is ill-conditioned).

Comment: Should it be $\min_{c \in K_k} \| b - Ac \|_2$ rather than $\min_{c \in K_k} \| r_0 - Ac \|_2$?

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response.

Comment: @littleO If $x_k=x_0+c_k$, then $r_k=b-Ax_k=b-Ax_0-Ac_k=r_0-Ac_k$. I assume $x_0$ is not necessarily zero.